# Deterministic random number generation in duckdb with dplyr syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow, duckdb

How can I use duckdb's `setseed()` function ([see reference doc](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/functions/numeric.html)) with dplyr syntax to make sure the analysis below is reproducible?

```r
# dplyr version 1.1.1
# arrow version 11.0.0.3
# duckdb 0.7.1.1
out_dir <- tempfile()
arrow::write_dataset(mtcars, out_dir, partitioning = "cyl")

mtcars_ds <- arrow::open_dataset(out_dir)

mtcars_smry <- mtcars_ds |>
  arrow::to_duckdb() |>
  dplyr::mutate(
    fold = ceiling(3 * random())
  ) |>
  dplyr::summarize(
    avg_hp = mean(hp),
    .by = c(cyl, fold)
  )

mtcars_smry |>
  dplyr::collect()
#> Warning: Missing values are always removed in SQL aggregation functions.
#> Use `na.rm = TRUE` to silence this warning
#> This warning is displayed once every 8 hours.
#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>     cyl  fold avg_hp
#>   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     4     1   92  
#> 2     4     3   82.3
#> 3     4     2   74.5
#> 4     8     2  183. 
#> 5     8     3  210  
#> 6     8     1  300. 
#> 7     6     3  110  
#> 8     6     1  117  
#> 9     6     2  175
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Since I have been able to get this to work reliably with `DBI`-based connections but not (yet) after `arrow::to_duckdb()`, I suggest we need the [tag:arrow] and [tag:duckdb] tags, would you agree?

Comment: I wonder if my inability to do with with `to_duckdb()` suggests that there is some reconnection and/or re-seeding going on in the background. No combination of `to_duckdb(con=, auto_disconnect=)` remedies the problem, but my more direct SQL-based answer suggests that the duckdb `setseed` is working conceptually, so something in the `to_duckdb` chain must be upsetting the flow. Thoughts?

Comment: Found [this article](https://www.christophenicault.com/post/large_dataframe_arrow_duckdb/) when I was searching for an answer. You can couple your approach with the ideas presented in the linked article and hopefully it should work!

Comment: I don't see anything in that article that suggests internals of the duckdb/arrow interaction that answers the problem: why is the seed honored when using `DBI` but not after `to_duckdb`?

Comment: I think it's a matter of disposed connections and such. For instance, if I do `mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * coalesce(setseed(0.5), random())))` with my `mtcars_tbl` below, the first return value is different, but the second _and all subsequent_ (assuming the same query repeated over and over with no other queries in between) are all the same. I think the `setseed(.)` is not used in the current/immediate query but in the _next_ query of the current connection. I can't get any combination of `con=` or `auto_disconnect=` to not look like it's re-initiating the connection (and ergo the seed)

Comment: @r2evans, do you think it would be worthwhile to open an issue on arrow's GitHub repo?

Comment: Yes I do, where they will have much more awareness of the internals to know if this is a bug or how to explain what is flawed in our assumption of this. If it is resolved there, _please_ come back and either comment or provide another answer.

Answer (score 4):

`setseed()` needs to be within a query; while it doesn't necessarily make full sense in one way (since it returns null/`NA`), it's at least clear. We can include it in its own "query".

A quick helper function, for convenience:

```r
use_setseed <- function(tab, seed = 0.5) {
  ign <- tab |>
    summarize(a = setseed(seed)) |>
    head(n = 1) |>
    collect()
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

An important note about this is that it *must* "realize" the query (typically `collect()` it) in order for the `setseed()` call to be actually executed. Since we need to realize it, but we don't need any of its data, I reduce the data passed back by "summarizing" (one row, one column), then collecting it, then discarding it with `invisible()`.

Also, this is working on a more-direct connection,

```r
duck <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, "mtcars", mtcars)
mtcars_tbl <- tbl(duck, "mtcars")
```

From here, we just need to call `use_setseed` immediately before our randomizing query.

```r
use_setseed(mtcars_tbl)
mtcars_tbl |>
  dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |>
  dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) )
# # Source:   SQL [9 x 3]
# # Database: DuckDB 0.8.1 [r2@Linux 6.2.0-27-generic:R 4.2.3/:memory:]
#     cyl  fold avg_hp
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     6     1  110  
# 2     4     1   83.5
# 3     8     3  210  
# 4     6     3  114  
# 5     4     3   79.7
# 6     6     2  149  
# 7     8     1  174  
# 8     8     2  252. 
# 9     4     2   97  

# validation
use_setseed(mtcars_tbl)
res1 <- mtcars_tbl |>
  dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) ) |>
  dplyr::collect()
resn <- replicate(10, {
  use_setseed(mtcars_tbl)
  mtcars_tbl |>
    dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |> 
    dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) ) |> 
    dplyr::collect()
}, simplify=FALSE)
sapply(resn, identical, res1)
#  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

---

Equivalently, if you have a duckdb connection object, we can reduce the bandwidth a little more by using this version of the function:

```r
use_setseed2 <- function(con, seed=0.5) {
  DBI::dbExecute(con, "select setseed(?) as ign", params = list(seed))
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

And calling it with the `duckdb`-connection object, as in

```r
use_setseed2(duck) # note 'duck' and not 'mtcars_tbl'
mtcars_tbl |>
  dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) )
# same as above

# validation
use_setseed2(duck)
res1 <- mtcars_tbl |>
  dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |> 
  dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) ) |>
  dplyr::collect()
resn <- replicate(10, {
  use_setseed2(duck)
  mtcars_tbl |>
    dplyr::mutate(fold = ceiling(3 * random())) |> 
    dplyr::summarize(avg_hp = mean(hp), .by = c(cyl, fold) ) |> 
    dplyr::collect()
}, simplify=FALSE)
sapply(resn, identical, res1)
#  [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```